# Javascript - Creating number with specific formula modulo11

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

I created following generator for Czech tax number (IČO). I know that there is certainly better way how to code that in javascript. I am beginner and I would like to see how to write my code properly. The number is created with special formula and it has 8didgits, tha last digit is based on modulo11 as you can see below in code.

Thanks for your replies.

```js
 //Generation of single random numbers as variables
 var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var f = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 //Formula for tax number
 var formula = a * 8 + b * 7 + c * 6 + d * 5 + e * 4 + f * 3 + g * 2;
 var modulo11 = formula % 11;
 if (modulo11 === 0) {
   var h = 1;
 } else if (modulo11 === 1) {
   var h = 0;
 } else {
   var h = 11 - modulo11;
 };
 //Completing tax number
 var identificationNumber = "" + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h;
 //displaying number in console
 console.log(identificationNumber);
```

Comment: Other than a couple of style things, what's wrong with the code? What is it you think should be better? (And if this is working, I'd suggest reading the [How to Ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and consider posting there instead of here if appropriate.)

Comment: It is working fine, but I think I am repeating lot of code and that the code for first 7 digits(7 random numbers) should be written more effectively.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code, if it's working, to be honest why change it ... It's not always about the 'less' lines of code... You also need to keep the aspect of readability into account.

Comment: Then it's not a question for SO. As I say, it *may* be one for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code review question. It **may** be on-topic for http://codereview.stackexchange.com but check their help first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take benefit from `Array` data structure to store `a`, `b`,...`g`.
- Then "map" this array by `(8- indexOfItem) * item`

  so , for the 1ˢᵗ item which has index = 0 , we will have `(8 - 0) * a` -➡ `8* a`.

  for the 2ⁿᵈ item ➡ `(8 -1) * b` ➡ `7 *b`

  ....so on.
- Then use "reduce" to calculate the sum .
- Then use "join" instead of `""+ a +b + ....+ g+ h`

```js
function getH(modulo11) {
 if (modulo11 === 0)  return 1;
 if (modulo11 === 1)  return 0;
 return 11 - modulo11;
}

//Generation of single random numbers as variables
const numbers= Array.from({length: 7},(v, k) =>Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))  

 //Formula for tax number
const formula= numbers.map((n, i) => (8 - i) * n).reduce((total, next) => total+ next , 0)// alternative of sum : a * 8 + b * 7 + c * 6 + d * 5 + e * 4 + f * 3 + g * 2

const h= getH(formula % 11);

 //Completing tax number
const identificationNumber = [...numbers, h].join('');
 //displaying number in console
 console.log(identificationNumber);
```

Comment: never heard of `mapFn`, the second parameter of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: i mean i have not really used `Array.from` and the API of it. Thank you for an example with callback.